# Accent sensitive querytable in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a sub in VBA which checks if I have been undercut on an online bookstore. The problem is, many authors and titles have accented characters in them, which, as far as I have experienced, I cant but into a querytable. For example the charactera á,é,ö become strange symbols like @ or $ when I try to load a webpage.

I am attaching the code I have so far:

```
For i = 1 To Sorok
        Nev(i) = Ekezet(Sheets(AdatokLap).Cells(i + 1, 4)
        KonyvCim(i) = Ekezet(Sheets(AdatokLap).Cells(i + 1, 5)
        ConnectString = "URL;http://bookline.hu/search/search.action?     inner=true&searchfield=" & Nev(i) & " " & KonyvCim(i) & "&tab=bookline.hu%2Foldbook"

    Set qt = Sheets(QueryLap).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=ConnectString, Destination:=Cells(1, 1))
    With qt
        .Name = "MyName"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

I have written a function, called Ekezet(), which removes all accented characters from a string. Is there any way I don't have to remove accented characters and still run a web query?